# docker-compose get Container Name from inside of the Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do I get the Name of a container from inside that container in docker-compose?

I need the name, because it needs to be the same, even if the service is stopped and later restared (meaning that the ID will not suffice). I also need a different name for each instance of the container (because I need to be able to differentiate the containers when they were scaled).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an auto generated container-name, you can define the name of the container in your docker-compose file, see the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name):

**container_name**
Specify a custom container name, rather than a generated default name.

```
container_name: my-web-container
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the container name dynamically by `docker-compose` you can execute the below command.

`$(docker inspect -f '{{.Name}}' $(./devbox docker-compose ps -q web) | cut -c2-)`

If you want to get the container name within the container then can execute the below command.

`cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep "cpu:/" | sed 's/\([0-9]\):cpu:\/docker\///g'`

Comment: Unfortunately, your second command only gives me the Container ID and not the name.